# Template parse errors -> Can't bind to 'ngforOf' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-item'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I get data from web service already and in my html page I want to render this data. I use `*ngfor` to loop through the data :

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngfor="let item of items">
        {{item.Problem}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

but it returns this :

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngforOf' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-item'.
1. If 'ion-item' is an Angular component and it has 'ngforOf' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-item' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
    <ion-list>

        <ion-item [ERROR ->]*ngfor="let item of items">

            {{item.Problem}}
"): ng:///AppModule/RedditsPage.html@14:18
Property binding ngforOf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("
    <ion-list>

        [ERROR ->]<ion-item *ngfor="let item of items">

            {{item.Problem}}
"): ng:///AppModule/RedditsPage.html@14:8
```

I checked the ngfor syntax already, how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be `*ngFor`

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
```